# expect password when prompted

Tags: shell, ssh

When we try to access the remote host server in the bellow manner its asking me for password.

```
]# ssh remotehost
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
Password:
Last login: Tue Apr 25 05:54:32 2017 from pm.remothost
Copyright (c) 2001-2014 EMC Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
Copyright (c) 1992-2011 The FreeBSD Project.
Copyright (c) 1979, 1980, 1983, 1986, 1988, 1989, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994
        The Regents of the University of California. All rights reserved.


remotehost-1#
```

Is there any way to give the password in ssh command like `sshpass` or `expect`.

There is a .ssh/config file which have accessing 2 jumphost before connecting the remotehost.

Can we do something like which can expect/give password when prompted and then we get the login.

Below is what we are trying but not working. It gives passphrase 3 time but when the last password is entered it comes out and no file is created in the local machine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set timeout 10

spawn ssh ip < ./ai.py >> stinfo_2017.txt
expect "Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':"
send "12345\r"
expect "Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':"
send "12345\r"
expect "Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':"
send "12345\r"
expect "Password:"
send "54321\r"
interact
```

When running the script the output is like this.

```
[root@centseven ~]# ./directconnect
spawn ssh ip < ./ai.py >> stinfo_2017.txt
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
Password: 
zsh: no such file or directory: ./ai.py
Killed by signal 1.
Killed by signal 1.
[root@centseven ~]#
```

The script is not getting executed on the remote server, hence there is no file created stinfo_2017.txt.

When we run this manually it creates a file.

Comment: try `ssh-copy-id`.

Comment: We already have a keygen created with passphrase. We need a script which will give same password for first 3 prompt and the last one will have a different password.

Comment: as per the policy we cant remove the passphrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in the spawn line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set timeout 10

spawn sc -h "ssh ip < ./ai.py >> stinfo_2017.txt"
expect "Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':"
send "12345\r"
expect "Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':"
send "12345\r"
expect "Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':"
send "12345\r"
expect "Password:"
send "54321\r"
interact
```